# Vue.js- How to extract the text content of children element/s?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I am building a pagination component for an application with lot of data in Vue.js. I have come across the pagination component in Vuetify in the process. I am intending to make an api call each time I change the page number to refresh the data. I have added the component successfully, so now I want to change the response array depending upon the text content of the page number **<span>** element.

I have come across $refs method and also, ParentNode.children method. But I didn't exactly understand how to use them in my case.

**PaginationCode.vue**

```
<ul class="v-pagination__list">
  <li class="v-pagination__item" data-test="v-pagination-item">
    <button
      type="button"
      class="v-btn v-btn--icon v-theme--currentTheme text-primary"
      ellipsis="false"
      aria-current="false"
      aria-label="Go to page 1"
    >
      <span class="v-btn__overlay"></span><span class="v-btn__underlay"></span>
      <span class="v-btn__content" data-no-activator="">1</span>
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="v-pagination__item" data-test="v-pagination-item">
    <button
      type="button"
      class="v-btn v-btn--icon v-theme--currentTheme text-primary"
      ellipsis="false"
      aria-current="false"
      aria-label="Go to page 1"
    >
      <span class="v-btn__overlay"></span><span class="v-btn__underlay"></span>
      <span class="v-btn__content" data-no-activator="">2</span>
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="v-pagination__item" data-test="v-pagination-item">
    <button
      type="button"
      class="v-btn v-btn--icon v-theme--currentTheme text-primary"
      ellipsis="false"
      aria-current="false"
      aria-label="Go to page 1"
    >
      <span class="v-btn__overlay"></span><span class="v-btn__underlay"></span>
      <span class="v-btn__content" data-no-activator="">3</span>
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This code gives the belowattached image as Output. So, I am expecting to extract the text content of the below span element. Simply put, If I click on the list element with text content as 1 in its child elements, I have to extract "1"  and so on.

[Pagination Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahu6q.png)

Comment: This is potential XY problem. Extracting data from html is a hack which you possibly could use if this were browser addon that works with someone else's app. Since you control your app, you should be able to know which page you're currently at.